# Oozie -Pyspark Job throwing error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, oozie

I am trying to schedule pyspark job in Oozie (CDH 5.7), But it's been throwing error. Please find my workflow below.

I have put the .py script in local path and also hdfs path. Please let me know if I need to modify anything.

**Error:
[org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exit code [1]**

```
<workflow-app name="Spark_on_Oozie" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
  <global>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.launcher.yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
                    <value>SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
  </global>
    <start to="spark-9fa1"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark-9fa1">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>spak_job</name>
             <class>clear</class>
            <jar>/home/cloudera/DQ_FRAMEWORK/oozie/application/app_amlmkte_dq/wf_prc_l1_dq/dq_prc_ini_com_spark.py</jar>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>


Pyspark Job (Only Put the small code to test):

if __name__ == "__main__":

    sc = SparkContext(appName="Aml Markets DQ")
    sqlContext=HiveContext(sc)
    dt1=datetime.datetime.now()
    dq_exec_start_tm=('%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%d'%(dt1.year,dt1.month,dt1.day,dt1.hour,dt1.minute,dt1.second,dt1.microsecond))[:-4]
    #dq_batch_start_id=app_nm +'_'+('%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%d'%(dt.year,dt.month,dt.day,dt.hour,dt.minute,dt.second,dt.microsecond))[:-4]
    # Command Line Arguement
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

1. Pyspark job need to be hdfs path and it should be full path like hdsf://user/****
2. Need to include spark_home which I did already.

Thanks.